# Detour without endpoints

Tags: java, apache-camel

can I use choice without "to" as a part of route? E.g. I want to modify body when certain condition is met and then continue with the route:

```
from(...).
choice(...).
  when(...).
    setBody(...)
  end().  // of when()???
end().  // of choice()??
to(...).
to(...);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to end the when condition and how to end the choice so I can continue with my route. The [detour](http://camel.apache.org/detour.html) and [endChoice()](http://camel.apache.org/why-can-i-not-use-when-or-otherwise-in-a-java-camel-route.html) samples do use endpoints inside the construct. Is there documentation where I can use the end() construct? Is this a good way how to write camel DSL when there are more conditions? Should I use Direct component instead and keep each condition in separate route?

Kind regards, Jan

Comment: Did you try it? I think it should work (although I think to end the `when()` you should use `endChoice()`). Using `end()` at the end of a `choice()` construct should return to the original route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in the Camel book, correct construct should look like:

```
from(...).
choice(...).
  when(...).
  setBody(...)
end().  // of choice()
// continue with the original route
to(...).
to(...);
```

The **endChoice()** is needed only to end **when()** when the body of when also might require an **end()**, such as **loadBalance()** or **split()**.